# How to add the Top Nav Bar in the Modern SharePoint Team Site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I want to **move my Quick Launch Bar to the Top Nav Bar** in my Modern SharePoint Team Site.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an Extension to your site.
Official demo:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions

The demo create two parts, the top placeholder and the bottom placeholder, you need to delete the bottom one.

The quick launch bar values you can get by this rest endpoint: `/_api/web/Navigation/QuickLaunch`